# Create combination of two pandas dataframes in two dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, df1 and df2. I want to create a dataframe df3 that contains all combinations using one column in df1 and one column in df2. The pseudocode of doing this inefficiently would be something like this:

```
df3 = []
for i in df1:
     for j in df2:
         df3.append(i + j) # where i + j is the row with the combined cols from df1 and df2
```

Here's the format for df1:

```
df1_id    other_data_1    other_data_2
1         0               1
2         1               5
```

df2:

```
df2_id    other_data_3    other_data_4
1         0               1
3         2               2
```

And the goal is to get this output for
df3:

```
df1_id    df2_id    other_data_1    other_data_2    other_data_3    other_data_4
1         1         0               1               0               1
1         3         0               1               2               2
2         1         1               5               0               1
2         3         1               5               2               2
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Update pandas 1.2.0+

```
df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

---

Set a common key between the two dataframes and use `pd.merge`:

```
df1['key'] = 1
df2['key'] = 1
```

Merge and drop key column:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='key').drop('key',axis=1)
df3
```

Output:

```
   df1_id  other_data_1  other_data_2  df2_id  other_data_3  other_data_4
0       1             0             1       1             0             1
1       1             0             1       3             2             2
2       2             1             5       1             0             1
3       2             1             5       3             2             2
```

Comment: That's great solution but it would be super slow for 'big dataframes'

Comment: Is there no better way to do this? Like without using merge specifically?

Comment: @MitaliCyrus What is particular wrong with this solution?  You want to cause a cartesian product in rows from each dataframe.

Comment: @ScottBoston You are correct. The solution itself works very well (Thank you). I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this that didn't require adding columns and then dropping them after.

Comment: @MitaliCyrus You can use assign to temporarily create keys in both tables then drop the key for the result if you don't needed.  `df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)`

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks. :)