# Reading new data from constantly updated files row-by-row to use for further calculations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, gps

I have two GPS modules which are placed on a vehicle (e.g. front and back), both modules are separately parsing NMEA messages. The parsed data (lon and lat of both modules) is being written to two .csv files (e.g. dataFRONT.csv and dataBACK.csv).
The data is continuously being written to the files approx. once per second. Since the data from the "front" module is being sent to the "back" module by BLE, it has a slight delay - which results in both .csv files not being updated at the same rate (which probably doesn't really matter for my issue).

For a project I'm working on, I need to calculate the distance and bearing between both modules. To do so, I'm trying to constantly read both lists and calculate the distance and bearing by "picking" the latest row appended to both files. That's exactly where I'm struggling..
**Is there a way or does someone have an idea to permanently "tail" both .csv files and pick out the newly appended rows for such calculations?**

With the code I have now, it immediately reads both files and spits out about 1000 rows of results, although only about 30 rows of coordinates have been written to both files. The code looks something like this:

```
df1=pd.read_csv("dataFRONT.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("dataBACK.csv")
df1_size=df1.shape[0]
df2_size=df2.shape[0]

for i in range(df1_size):
  for j in range(df2_size):
     s1=(df1['Latitude1'].iloc[i], df1['Longitude1'].iloc[i])
     s2=(df2['Latitude2'].iloc[j], df2['Longitude2'].iloc[j])
     distance=haversine(s1,s2)
     dist.append(distance)

 with open('distance.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
     writer=csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(zip(dist))
```

Here's a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71862366/how-can-i-optimize-a-python-code-to-calculate-distance-between-two-gps-points), but it didn't work out either. In both situations, it seemed to somehow merge both files and as a result, output an (nearly)infinite list of results - which is of course not what I want. **I would like to output the result (distance between two GPS coordinates) row-by-row and as soon as two new coordinates get appended to their file.**

*Note*: What I've tried as well, is generating sort of an ID for each new row appended, trying to only get the corresponding values for the calculation (Pseudo: "if df1['ID'] == df2['ID'], get both coordinate-pairs and calculate distance between them ...)

I know that there might be similar questions out there, but I haven't found an answer for my specific question and I would really appreciate your help (btw: sorry, I'm still a rookie and learning!)

***Edit:*** The NMEA messages I receive, look something like this before I parse them: *$--GLL,llll.lll,a,yyyyy.yyy,b,hhmmss.sss,A,a*hh*, with llll.lll being Latitude and yyyyy.yyy being Longitude. In my code, I parse the messages I want (GLL) and put them in a queue. After that, they get appended to the corresponding .csv file. The dataframe look something like this: (This could be dataFRONT.csv for example.. The formatting of dataBACK.csv is exactly the same)

```
   Latitude1  Longitude1
0  XX.92121   XX.41845
1  XX.92225   XX.41867
2  XX.92256   XX.41879
3  XX.92370   XX.41898
4  XX.92168   XX.41599
```

Comment: Can you share a couple of lines from your CSVs/(Pre-Modifications)DataFrames in your question?

Comment: @BeRT2me, I added the lines of my /CSVDataframe to the question!

Comment: If you just want the last line of a pandas dataframe, you can access it with `df.iloc[-1]`, but I think pandas is overkill for your situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer below. I'll give it a try tomorrow!
Just cause I'm curious, how would you solve it with a dataframe and `df.iloc[-1]` ? Would a double for-loop as I tried above be the correct approach?

Comment: For-loops are basically never the answer when it comes to pandas, any case that you think a for loop would be absolutely necessary, probably needs to use `.apply()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given CSVs that look something like:

```
Latitude1,Longitude1
99.92225,99.41867
99.92256,99.41879
99.9237,99.41898
99.92168,99.41599
```

---

```py
import os
import time

def get_last_line(f):
    # Method to quickly and efficiently find the last line of a file.
    try:  # catch OSError in case of a one line file 
        f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
        while f.read(1) != b'\n':
            f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
    except OSError:
        f.seek(0)
    return f.readline().decode()

def refresh_distance():
    # Reads Front and Back CSVs, gets last line, extracts data.
    # Appends distance.csv with the most recent distance calculation.
    with open("dataFRONT.csv", "rb") as front, open("dataBACK.csv", "rb") as back:
        # Opens both files, extracting applicable variables.
        lat_front, long_front = get_last_line(front).split(',')
        lat_back, long_back = get_last_line(back).split(',')
    # Converts all to floats, there's probably a better way to do this.
    lat_front, long_front = float(lat_front), float(long_front)
    lat_back, long_back = float(lat_back), float(long_back)
    # Calculates the distance:
    distance = haversine((lat_front, long_front),(lat_back, long_back))

    # Appends new distance to file.
    with open('distance.csv', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(distance) + '\n')

# Runs the refresh, once per second, runs forever...
while True:
    refresh_distance()
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

If you want to use a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Reads just the first (header) and last line into a dataframe.
with open("dataFRONT.csv", "rb") as front, open("dataBACK.csv", "rb") as back:
    # Uses the same get_last_line as above.
    df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(front.readline().decode() + get_last_line(front)))
    df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(back.readline().decode() + get_last_line(back)))

distance = haversine(df1.iloc[-1], df2.iloc[-1])

... # You can write the same as above, 
... # and wrap it in a function and while loop like above to run it continuously~
```

---

Bonus, how I'd get the distance for every value comparing two DataFrames.

Example DataFrames, different lengths since that sounds like a possibility, use that nifty timestamp you say you have...:

```
# df1:
   Latitude1  Longitude1  timestamp
0   99.92225    99.41867  052556.452
1   99.92256    99.41879  052557.243
2   99.92370    99.41898  052558.456
3   99.92168    99.41599  052600.258

# df2:
   Latitude2  Longitude2   timestamp
1  100.92256   100.41879  052556.789
2  100.92370   100.41898  052557.486
3  100.92168   100.41599  052559.768
```

Format Timestamps and make them the index:

```
df1.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df1.timestamp.astype(str), format='%H%M%S.%f')
df2.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df2.timestamp.astype(str), format='%H%M%S.%f')
df1.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
```

Merge them on the nearest timestamps, with a tolerance of 1 second:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s'))
```

Now we can create a distance column:

```
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: haversine((x.Latitude1, x.Longitude1), (x.Latitude2, x.Longitude2)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                         Latitude1  Longitude1  Latitude2  Longitude2    distance
timestamp
1900-01-01 05:25:56.452   99.92225    99.41867        NaN         NaN         NaN
1900-01-01 05:25:57.243   99.92256    99.41879  100.92256   100.41879  112.995860
1900-01-01 05:25:58.456   99.92370    99.41898  100.92370   100.41898  112.996248
1900-01-01 05:26:00.258   99.92168    99.41599  100.92168   100.41599  112.995561
```

Or you could resample to the nearest second on merge, which creates the framework for a very nice timeline imo:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1.resample('s').nearest(), df2.resample('s').nearest(), left_index=True, right_index=True, tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1s'))
df3['distance'] = df3.apply(lambda x: haversine((x.Latitude1, x.Longitude1), (x.Latitude2, x.Longitude2)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                     Latitude1  Longitude1  Latitude2  Longitude2    distance
timestamp
1900-01-01 05:25:56   99.92225    99.41867  100.92256   100.41879  113.030155
1900-01-01 05:25:57   99.92256    99.41879  100.92256   100.41879  112.995860
1900-01-01 05:25:58   99.92370    99.41898  100.92370   100.41898  112.996248
1900-01-01 05:25:59   99.92370    99.41898  100.92168   100.41599  112.764205
1900-01-01 05:26:00   99.92168    99.41599  100.92168   100.41599  112.995561
```